# SQL Server JSON manipulation

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using JSON data as a way to keep order details in a single `nvarchar` "orders" table column.
Initially I used the "common" way of creating an array of objects (using "for JSON path") - but soon enough found out there's no way to update the array's individual objects - only by index/position - which is useless, or replacing the whole JSON string - which is crazy. (or is there?).

Anyway, I figured that if I change the array of objects into a dictionary - I would be able to update a single item/object with a simple `json_modify` command.

So I moved from this:

```
[
    {
        "File": 350464,
        "Bin": 143601,
        "Status": 1
    },
    {
        "File": 350743,
        "Bin": 143610,
        "Status": 2
    },
    {
        "File": 350956,
        "Bin": 143615,
        "Status": 2
    },
    {
        "File": 351350,
        "Bin": 143498,
        "Status": 1
    }
]
```

To this:

```
{
    "350517":{"bin":143602,"status":1},
    "350641":{"bin":143607,"status":1},
    "350745":{"bin":143610,"status":2},
    "350805":{"bin":143611,"status":2},
    "358898":{"bin":145461,"status":1}
}
```

Now I'm stuck at the other end - when trying to read the JSON as a table result.
This is what I use:

```
SELECT files.*, JSON_VALUE(files.value, '$.bin') [Bin], JSON_VALUE(files.value, '$.status') [Status]
FROM OPENJSON(@json) files
```

And this is the result:

```
key value   type    Bin Status
350517  {"bin":143602,"status":1}   5   143602  1
350641  {"bin":143607,"status":1}   5   143607  1
350745  {"bin":143610,"status":1}   5   143610  1
350805  {"bin":143611,"status":1}   5   143611  1
358898  {"bin":145461,"status":1}   5   145461  1
```

Finally! I'm so close... as you see from the results above, I can get the "bin" and "status" data from the JSON into the result set's columns using `json_value`.

My question is: how can I get the "key" data into my result's column? I can see it when selecting "*" (as seen above) but I hate selecting *'s. how do I refer to it directly? And while at it, where's the "type" column coming from, and what does "5" mean?

Comment: Why not use a normalised design in the first place? JSON/XML data isn't best suited for storing such data in a database and you wouldn't need to even attempt to attempt the mess you're doing right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried selecting your `key` value?

```sql
declare @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
    "350517":{"bin":143602,"status":1},
    "350641":{"bin":143607,"status":1},
    "350745":{"bin":143610,"status":2},
    "350805":{"bin":143611,"status":2},
    "358898":{"bin":145461,"status":1}
}';

select
  [key] as [file],
  json_value(value, '$.bin') as [bin],
  json_value(value, '$.status') as [status]
from openjson(@json);
```

Which yields:

| file | bin | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 350517 | 143602 | 1 |
| 350641 | 143607 | 1 |
| 350745 | 143610 | 2 |
| 350805 | 143611 | 2 |
| 358898 | 145461 | 1 |

Comment: oops!. you're right! i tried files.key, and json_value(files.key, '$'), but didnt get to just [key]. cheers mate!

Comment: And as for @Larnu's comment - the order is going back and forth between un-connected systems - so i think json strings are a better choice, dont you?